# Proving if $a,b$ are even and $c$ is odd, then $ax+by=c$ doesn't have any solutions in $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z$. Prove that if $a,b$ are even and $c$ is odd, then $ax+by=c$ doesn't have any solutions in $\mathbb N$.

I get that sometimes this can acutally be false. Define $a=2k,b=2l,c=2n+1, k,l,n\in \mathbb Z$ so after a bit of manipulation we get $y=-\frac lk x+\frac {2n+1}{2k}$ so this line can actually cross the postive $x$ axis.

Is this question actually wrong?

Comment: even integer + even integer can't be an odd integer

Comment: Yes, but where ? I.e. the point $((2n+1)/2l, 0)$ has both coordinates belonging to $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ah I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not wrong. Note that it says "solutions in $\mathbb{N}$."
There is no reason your $y$ should be a natural number.

For an argument, recall that since if $a$ is even and $x$ is an ineteger then $ax$ is even, same for $by$ and you see the contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is that the equation has no solutions *in the integers*. It is true there's a *real* (even *rational*) solution, but the $x$ and $y$ can't both be integers.

Answer (score 1):

The question is correct as it asks for integer solutions. And even integer plus even integer can't be odd. So no integer solutions.